# How to return an json Object and catch in in Ajax call in HTML

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I have a simple tree structure of information in my D3 code. The D3 script is calling  json from the script d3.json() function and the resulting json is giving the tree structure data.Now I have a couple of information that will come from database and hit the Servlet. I have to make the json dynamically in the Servlet so that it can change upon user response.Here is the  script & the json I used..

This is my HTML file from where I made an Ajax call to the Servlet. The Ajax is calling the Servlet 
,but there is an error in getting back the response. I am getting an "error occurred" message.When I am running the servlet......

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>            
        function doajax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "AccountServlet",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",

                error:function(){
                    alert("error occured!!!");
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data.fullName + "\n" + data.mobileNo);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This is the Html from where i am tring to get the response back
this file just calls a Servlet.But in the response i am getting a error occuree message ...

IN the accountServlet i am creating the json like this

```
     ArrayList<DistinctSourceCount> countList = new ArrayList<DistinctSourceCount>();
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Jan", 1800));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Feb", 1500));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("March", 2000));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("April", 1550));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("May", 1000));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("June", 1700));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("July", 1400));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Aug", 1900));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Sept", 1000));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Oct", 1500));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Nov", 1100));
        countList.add(new DistinctSourceCount("Dec", 2000));

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray arrayObj = new JsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < countList.size(); i++) {
            DistinctSourceCount count = countList.get(i);
            JsonElement linObj = gson.toJsonTree(count);
            arrayObj.add(linObj);
        }

        JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
        myObj.addProperty("success", true);
        myObj.add("topList", arrayObj);
        myObj.addProperty("totalCount", countList.size());

        System.out.println(myObj.toString());
        System.out.close();
```

This is my code I have done so far.Can anyone help me about how to create the json object in Servlet and getting the  response back the script??please anyone help

Comment: it's better you have a RESTful framework like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) or [resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create json Object in the servlet. And then retrive that json using ajax call in your script. For creating json in servlet you can use any library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [java-json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm).

For example:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name","flare");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject_child = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject_child.put("name", "analytics");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject_child);
        jsonObject.put("children",jsonArray);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

And the ajax code as below:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PATH_OF_SERVLET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
        // Parse your response from Servlet here.
        }

    });
```

Comment: will it return a response to html ??

Comment: @lucifer you have to add the contents of json dynamicallty to html by the id or class of the that element.

Comment: you please see my new edit i am calling the Servlet using this HTML file

Comment: @lucifer in your servlet, print the json ,  You are using System.out.print(), instead you have to use PrintWriter class : PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); out.print(myObj) . Dont stringify your json

Comment: is my json creation  ok??? i mean if i call this from HTML will it give a  response to me??

Comment: Can you also include DistinctSourceCount class, so i can check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39826/discussion-between-lucifer-and-jhanvi)

Comment: Its my HTML file from where i am calling the Servlet please check if there is anything wrong .. i am posting it...in the place of  DistinctSourceCount class