# Ajax request call to the servlet doesn't return anything

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

This is my jquery function. It should pass to the servlet two value and get back an update value. I checked if the values are taken correctly and the two variables are filled correctly. Unforuntately I don't get nothing back.

```
 $("#passengers").change(function(event){

    var passengers = $("#passengers").val();
    var price = $("#price").text();

        $.getJSON('pricer', {passengers: passengers, price: price}, function(data){

            $("#price").html(data);

        });
```

});

here is the servlet

```
        */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String passengers = request.getParameter("passengers");
    String price = request.getParameter("price");

    String price_update = new Gson().toJson(this.pricerBean.calculatePrice(Integer.parseInt(passengers), Float.parseFloat(price)));

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(price_update);   
}
```

The main problem is I don't get any error...even one...the javascript console error is empty and even the servlet doesn't show any errors

Comment: where have you return in method ?

Comment: Which return method do you mean? In the servlet?

Comment: Yes I am talking about servlet doPost method.

Comment: doPost does need a return method ?

Comment: I think he means that you are not writing to the response in doPost.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(data)); //here data is what you want to send
```

first try this simple :

response.getWriter().write("Hello");

in ajax :

```
    $.get('pricer', {passengers: passengers, price: price}, function(data){

        console.log(data);

    });
```

then try to run and what it prints post me.

console.log() prints data in browser console.

Comment: I posted the modified servlet

Comment: @Mazzy - okay let me try in my system and back to you.

Comment: @Mazzy - try only by sending simple `string` data instead of `Gson` first then check that is it work or not ?

Comment: by `response.getWriter().write("Hello");`

Comment: look here's what you want http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499572/how-to-return-an-json-object-and-catch-in-in-ajax-call-in-html#19536023

Comment: by executing response.getWriter.write("Hello") and calling pricer servlet I get a blank page

Comment: @Mazzy - will you update your code if you can ? new code

Answer (score 1):

use jquery `getJSON()` instead of `get()`

```
$.getJSON('pricer', {passengers: passengers, price: price}, function(data){
    $("#price").html(data.price_update);
});
```

or with `get`

```
$.get('pricer', {passengers: passengers, price: price}, function(data){
    // also validate data if it is  not blank
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $("#price").html(data.price_update);
});
```